# jQuery - Set the selected option of a select box using value or text with options nested in optgroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

So I am writing an app that requires an address input and I have a `select` element for the user to select the state/province. It needs to support the `US` and `Canada` so it has nested `optgroups` to separate those out and a single, first level option as it's default value. Here is a basic example:

```
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option class="co" value="" data-placeholder="true" disabled selected>Choose your state...</option>
  <optgroup label="United States">
    <option class="co" value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option class="co" value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option class="co" value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Canada">
    <option class="co" value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <option class="co" value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option class="co" value="MB">Manitoba</option>
  </optgroup>
```

Now I need to programmatically select the option that matches input from an external source and I want to check for a match based on both the value of the option element or its text. Whichever option is a match would then be set as the selected option. I know you can set the selected option by value using

```
$("#state").val(myValue)
```

and I know you can set an option based on text in this way

```
var myText = "The state I want.";
$("#state").children().filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == myText;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Is there a clean way to do this without having to run through each child and checking if it's an optgroup and then running through all its children to check for a match? Is there an easy way through jQuery to combine the value and text methods of setting the selected option?

One other complication, I am going to be doing this within an external jQuery plugin. Within the function I need to modify I have the select element as a variable

```
$element
```

so I need a way to do it kind of like this if possible:

```
$element.descendents(":option").filter(function() {
  //do the selecting here
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: perhaps using the has() class from jquery. http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: `$('#state option').filter(function(){ return $(this).text()===mytext;}).prop('selected', true);` ?

Comment: One other problem, I am doing this within a jQuery plugin so that function receives the select element as a parameter. I added this to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved. Since I already had my element passed to a function as a jQuery variable, $element, I couldn't just use the standard selector in the form of:

```
$("#state option").filter(
  // filter function
).prop('selected', true);
```

After a lot of trying, I got this and it works:

```
function functionIHadToChange($element, value) {
  // other code
  $element.find("option").filter(function(){
      return ( ($(this).val() == value) || ($(this).text() == value) )
    }).prop('selected', true);
}
```

Answer (score 26):

If you want to select by the option value, use the value selector:

```
var myText = "AZ";
$('#state option[value="' + myText + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

If you want to search by the option's label, use a filter:

```
var myText = "Arizona";
$('#state option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == myText; }).prop('selected', true)
```

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure I understood completely your question but I am attempting to answer it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/Bwpex/1/)

The trick being that you can select it by setting the value of the select box directly

```
$("#state").val( a_value );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it by  `$("#select_id").prop("selectedIndex", 3); // Select index starts from zero.`

Read here for example [this](http://kvcodes.com/2014/03/set-html-select-options-selected-value-using-jquery/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$element = $('select#state');
$options = $element.find('option');
$wanted_element = $options.filter(function () {
  return $(this).val() == "Alabama" || $(this).text() == "Alabama"
});
$wanted_element.prop('selected', true);
```

Would be one way to do it.

But i would guess, without knowing the exact internas of the `.find()` method, in the end jQuery will use at least two loops itself to perform this...

Comment: Looks like you just beat me to it. This is basically how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late here but for future visitor, easiest way to do that is :

## html

```
<select name="dept">
<option value="">This doctor belongs to which department?</option>
<option value="1">Orthopaedics</option>
<option value="2">Pathology</option>
<option value="3">ENT</option>
</select>
```

## jQuery

```
$('select[name="dept"]').val('3');
```

> Output: This will active **ENT**.